# como poder orgenar y relacionar los siguientes arreglos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, lógica

tengo los siguientes arreglos con objetos

```javascript
const PlantingOwner = [
    { id: 1, taxNumber: '126254524', name: 'DARIO OCHOA PEREZ' },
    { id: 2, taxNumber: '168618668', name: 'CRISTIAN RODRIGUEZ LEAL' },
    { id: 3, taxNumber: '78403228', name: 'DANILO GUTIERREZ ALVAREZ' },
    { id: 4, taxNumber: '216812737', name: 'ANDRES VIÑALES CIENFUEGOS' },
    { id: 5, taxNumber: '556352696', name: 'DANIEL IQUIRA ZUÑIGA' },
    { id: 6, taxNumber: '63684747', name: 'JUAN LUQUE SANDOVAL' }
];

const FruitsType = [
    { id: 1, name: 'MANZANAS' },
    { id: 2, name: 'NARANJAS' },
    { id: 3, name: 'BANANAS' },
    { id: 4, name: 'UVAS' },
];

const plantingArea = [
    { PlantingOwnerId: 6, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2019, area: 1300 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 1, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 4, harvestYear: 2019, area: 200 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2020, area: 30000 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 2, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2021, area: 7501 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 3, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2020, area: 3577 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2017, area: 66902 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 3, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2018, area: 2036 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 2, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2020, area: 3665 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 4, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 4, harvestYear: 2018, area: 6651 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2018, area: 400 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 1, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2019, area: 6956 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2020, area: 2745 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 6, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2021, area: 10362 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 2, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2021, area: 350 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 3, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2020, area: 14138 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 3, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2019, area: 18137 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 4, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2020, area: 100 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 2, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2019, area: 20845 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2018, area: 13969 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 1, grangeId: 3, plantingAreaTypeId: 1, harvestYear: 2029, area: 65420 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 5, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 3, harvestYear: 2010, area: 6500 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 6, grangeId: 1, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2012, area: 33587 },
    { PlantingOwnerId: 2, grangeId: 2, plantingAreaTypeId: 2, harvestYear: 2018, area: 99750 }
];

const farmsPlantingArea = [
    { id: 1, name: 'AGRICOLA SANTA MARTA' },
    { id: 2, name: 'VILLA SANTA LUCIA' },
    { id: 3, name: 'GRANJA SANTA GUTIERREZ' }
];
```

me piden un arreglo con los tipo de frutas que se cultivan, ordenados decrecientemente por la suma  TOTAL de la cantidad de hectáreas plantadas de cada uno de ellos

Quien puede ayudarme, quiero mejorar mi lógica para las diferente pruebas laborales que se presenten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea no es publicar un problema, y esperar soluciones, sino que también nos cuentes hasta donde has podido avanzar y en que te has trancado para que te podamos ayudar.

De todas formas, te dejo un ejemplo de como se puede resolver el problema planteado.

```
const fruitsDictionary = FruitsType.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.id] = obj.name;
  return acc;
}, {});

const totalPlantingAreaByType = plantingArea.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const { plantingAreaTypeId, area } = obj;
  const fruitName = fruitsDictionary[plantingAreaTypeId];
  const previousArea = acc[fruitName] ? acc[fruitName] : 0;
  acc[fruitName] = previousArea + area;

  return acc;
}, {});

const fruitsSortedByTotalPlanting = Object.entries(totalPlantingAreaByType)
  .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
  .map(([fruitName]) => fruitName);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón, para la próxima colocaré lo que había hecho, una pregunta sabes donde puedo estudiar o practicar ejercicios similares? Mucha s gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo probar https://www.hackerrank.com/.